# Feature Request: Topology

Tags: feature-request

I'm not sure how applicable this is, but I think that it would be a major help to have the ability to upload topologies along with questions, or as a response to one of the comments to one's question.

When it comes to network security design, being able to understand where firewalls/proxys/gateways/etc. are placed in the network via a visio or simple jpeg topology would be amazing.

The same could be applied to questions that just a flow chart would assist.  And i'm sure that other stack sites could make use of this too.

I know it's a big feature with a whole host of concerns (which oddly enough ties in well with this being an IT Security site), but it is something that would be beneficial for both new and seasoned members.

Comment: How is this need not equally served by the existing ability to post images?

Comment: My point is moot... i guess i've just never seen people do that.  I guess my idea was more being able to post a visio document... regardless I never noticed that you could post an image before.